# last_insert_id ? C#, SQL Server and NHibernate

Tags: c#, sql-server, nhibernate

I need to know how can I know what is the last inserted id in a SQL Server database for a  given table?

I'm using `int identity` not guid and if it's matters NHibernate as my ORM.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
var sql = "SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('TableName')";
var query = session.CreateSQLQuery(sql);
var result = query.UniqueResult();
```

This will return the last identity value generated for a given table.

Answer (score 4):

Depending on how your ID's are generated, you should be able to return it straight from the `ISession.Save()`:

```
int insertedID = (int)session.Save(entity);
```

Comment: thanks for reply. I have succesfully generated id's on saving entities, that's not the problem. Actually, I need to retrieve last inserted id not in current nhib. session.